# Rational scalar multiplication in Linear transformation using addition property

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Linear transformation: Map $T:V\to W$ is said to be Linear transformation when it satisfy property :

1) $L(u+v)=L(u)+L(v)\forall u,v \in V$

2)$L(cv)=cL(v) \quad \forall c\in \mathbb{F}$

I know when $c \in \mathbb N$ then property 2 can be obtained from property 1, since 
$$L(nv)= \underbrace{L(v)+L(v)......+L(v)}_{\text{$n$ times where $n \in \mathbb{N}$}}$$

> Now I have read in somewhere that if our scalar $c$ is rational then property 2 also follows from property 1, but I am unable to prove this.  How can I show that if $c \in \mathbb{Q}$, when (2) follows from (1)?

I know that if our scalar is irrational, then we cannot use property 1 to prove property 2.

Comment: What does “for irrational number it is indepedent of 1” mean? And what does$$L(nv)=L(v)+L(v)+\cdots+L(v)\ n\text{ times}$$mean if $n$ is, say $-\frac13$?

Comment: Sorry Sir @JoséCarlosSantos I had edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose our scalar $c$ is rational; that is $c = \frac{p}{q}$ for some integers $p$ and $q$.  Then, if $L$ satisfies property (1),
$$L(cv) = L \left(\frac{p}{q}v\right) = p L \left(\frac{1}{q} v \right)$$
by your previous result for integer scalars.  On the other hand,
$$L(v) = L\left( q\cdot \frac{1}{q} v \right) = q L\left(\frac{1}{q}v\right)$$
so, multiplying both sides by $1/q$,
$$L\left(\frac{1}{q}v\right) = \frac{1}{q} L(v)$$
returning to our first equation, this gives us that
$$L\left(\frac{p}{q} v\right) = \frac{p}{q}L(v)$$
so property (2) follows from property (1).